# Assigning into a dataframe by row

Tags: r

How do I assign by row to a data frame? These are the things that I have tried:

```
df <- data.frame(id=1:5)
df[c('x1','x2')] <- c(1,2)
df[c('x1','x2')] <- matrix(c(1,2),nrow=1)
df[c('x1','x2')] <- matrix(c(1,2),nrow=1,byrow=T)
```

The reason I want to do this is that I am generating a point from a multivariate normal distribution for each row.

Thanks!

Edit: I want the output to look like:

```
id x1 x2
1  1  1  2
2  2  1  2
3  3  1  2
4  4  1  2
5  5  1  2
```

But what I get is:

```
  id x1 x2
1  1  1  2
2  2  2  1
3  3  1  2
4  4  2  1
5  5  1  2
```

Comment: could you show the output you expect after doing all of this?

Comment: Edit: can I not do multiline code? Anyways, I want two columns added to lines: w0 and w1. w0 will equal 1 all the way down, and w1 will equal 2 all the way down. So the first row would have values: 1, 1, 2.

Comment: what's the output you obtain from the function? Could you show that as well as you obtain from the function..?

Comment: It's as simple as: `[1] 1 2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function returns a vector `c(1,2)`. Let's say it is in `x`.

```
df <- data.frame(id=1:5)
x <- 1:2 # function output.

df <- cbind(df, t(replicate(nrow(df), x)))
names(df) <- c("id", "x1", "x2")

> df

#   id x1 x2
# 1  1  1  2
# 2  2  1  2
# 3  3  1  2
# 4  4  1  2
# 5  5  1  2
```

If you have a bunch of 1*2 dimension vectors being returned from your function, then you'll have to first create a matrix of 5*2 and then `cbind`.

Is this what you're expecting?

Comment: Haha, yes, for this trivial example, that will do the trick. But I have a function that returns a 2-element vector. The idea is that I want to assign said vector to the two "slots" on each row.
Sorry, I should have made that more clear!

Comment: Please edit your post to show the output you require. I don't seem to understand what you want. What do you mean 2 element vector to be assigned to a row. You have a data.frame with 1 column and 5 rows. Do you want to bind it row-wise??

Comment: Currently, I am generating my 1x2 vectors sequentially and trying to add them, but I should be able to generate a Mx2 matrix of the values and cbind() it. I hadn't thought of that.. Thanks!

Comment: Yes! Except x is not constant. But I see now how to use cbind() to solve this. I will generate a 5x2 matrix first and cbind it. 

Thanks so much!

Comment: exactly. glad its resolved. and don't hesitate to write back if you run into problems. good luck!

Answer (score 0):

you are almost there!   put a comma after your expression inside of the `[ ]`

```
 df[c('x1','x2'),  ]  <-  <what you would like to assign>
```

Comment: That adds two new rows. I need two new columns! But thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here's why Arun's answer works, and an alternative:

You should avoid assigning a vector into a dataframe row, because R dataframes can have different variable types in each column. Imagine that your columns include numbers, strings, and factors; then a row of that dataframe is not a **vector** (because vectors must be all of one type, i.e. all numbers or all factors), but rather a **list**. If you try to assign a vector where R expects a list, bad things can happen.

But you can assign a list into a dataframe row. For example:

```
> df <- data.frame(id=1:5, x1=1, x2=2)
> df
  id x1 x2
1  1  1  2
2  2  1  2
3  3  1  2
4  4  1  2
5  5  1  2
> row2 <- list(x1=3, x2=4)
> df[2, c('x1','x2')] <- row2
> df
  id x1 x2
1  1  1  2
2  2  3  4
3  3  1  2
4  4  1  2
5  5  1  2
```

Or, if you know (as in your example) that everything's numeric, just build a matrix instead of a dataframe. Then you can assign vectors into matrix rows, no problem.

```
> mat <- matrix(c(1:5, rep(1,5), rep(2,5)), 5, 3)
> colnames(mat) <- c("id","x1","x2")
> mat
     id x1 x2
[1,]  1  1  2
[2,]  2  1  2
[3,]  3  1  2
[4,]  4  1  2
[5,]  5  1  2
> row2 <- c(3,4)
> mat[2, c("x1","x2")] <- row2
> mat
     id x1 x2
[1,]  1  1  2
[2,]  2  3  4
[3,]  3  1  2
[4,]  4  1  2
[5,]  5  1  2
```